# How to calculate average CPI for a pipelined processor?

Tags: performance, cpu, pipeline, forward, risc

For a question on a practice exam, it asks:

> Consider a program consisting of 100 `ld` instructions in which each instruction is dependent
>   on the instruction immediately preceding it, e.g.,
>
> `ld x2,0(x1)`
>
> `ld x3,0(x2)`
>
> `ld x4,0(x3)`
>
> What would the average CPI be in the pipelined processor with forwarding?

It also says the supposed answer is `(5 + (99 * 2)) / 100 = 2.03`. I understand 5 is the number of steps per instruction, and there are read/write processes for each step, however I have several questions regarding this:

1. First, why is 5 being added to 99*2 instead of multiplied, even though each instruction has 5 steps?
2. How would you calculate the answer assuming no forwarding?

Thanks!!

Comment: As someone who has worked in the field, I'm pretty sure that question doesn't make any sense without more context. What is "the pipelined processor"?

Comment: But I *think* what it's saying is that the first 99 instructions can forward with 2-cycle latency, but the last only retires in its 5th cycle since there's nothing to forward to. (This is a silly number and not really what people mean by CPI, but it would explain the math.)